# Tensorflow object detection api training error "TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api, nvidia-jetson

EDIT2

Ok so far i have tried with python3.5 -tf 1.10 and python 2.7 tf 1.10

I m still getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/model_main.py", line 101, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "object_detection/model_main.py", line 97, in main
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 455, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 594, in run
    return self.run_local()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 695, in run_local
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 354, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1179, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1209, in _train_model_default
    features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1167, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nvidia/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_lib.py", line 287, in model_fn
    prediction_dict, features[fields.InputDataFields.true_image_shape])
  File "/home/nvidia/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py", line 686, in loss
    keypoints, weights)
  File "/home/nvidia/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py", line 859, in _assign_targets
    groundtruth_weights_list)
  File "/home/nvidia/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/core/target_assigner.py", line 481, in batch_assign_targets
    anchors, gt_boxes, gt_class_targets, unmatched_class_label, gt_weights)
  File "/home/nvidia/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/core/target_assigner.py", line 180, in assign
    match = self._matcher.match(match_quality_matrix, **params)
  File "/home/nvidia/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/core/matcher.py", line 239, in match
    return Match(self._match(similarity_matrix, **params),
  File "/home/nvidia/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/matchers/argmax_matcher.py", line 190, in _match
    _match_when_rows_are_non_empty, _match_when_rows_are_empty)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2074, in cond
    orig_res_t, res_t = context_t.BuildCondBranch(true_fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 1920, in BuildCondBranch
    original_result = fn()
  File "/home/nvidia/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/matchers/argmax_matcher.py", line 153, in _match_when_rows_are_non_empty
    -1)
  File "/home/nvidia/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/matchers/argmax_matcher.py", line 203, in _set_values_using_indicator
    indicator = tf.cast(1-indicator, x.dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 878, in r_binary_op_wrapper
    x = ops.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=y.dtype.base_dtype, name="x")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1028, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1124, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 228, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 207, in constant
    value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 442, in make_tensor_proto
    _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 353, in _AssertCompatible
    (dtype.name, repr(mismatch), type(mismatch).__name__))
TypeError: Expected bool, got 1 of type 'int' instead.
```

Has anybody tried to train on TX2 or is it for my case only and i did something wrong?

ORIGINAL

Trying to train on mobilenet ssd on Jetson TX2 (I know it is not for taining but i have no better option)
followed these guides

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-with-tensorflows-object-detector-api-bec72ecfe1d9

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md

Training runs on my laptop (CPU) fine but i get the following error on my TX2

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 510, in _apply_op_helper
    preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1040, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 883, in _TensorTensorConversionFunction
    (dtype.name, t.dtype.name, str(t)))
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with dtype float32: 'Tensor("Loss/Loss/huber_loss/Sub_1:0", shape=(24, 1917, 4), dtype=float32)'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/model_main.py", line 101, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "object_detection/model_main.py", line 97, in main
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 425, in train_and_evaluate
    executor.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 504, in run
    self.run_local()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 636, in run_local
    hooks=train_hooks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 355, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 824, in _train_model
    features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 805, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nvidia/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_lib.py", line 287, in model_fn
    prediction_dict, features[fields.InputDataFields.true_image_shape])
  File "/home/nvidia/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py", line 708, in loss
    weights=batch_reg_weights)
  File "/home/nvidia/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/core/losses.py", line 74, in __call__
    return self._compute_loss(prediction_tensor, target_tensor, **params)
  File "/home/nvidia/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/core/losses.py", line 157, in _compute_loss
    reduction=tf.losses.Reduction.NONE
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/losses/losses_impl.py", line 444, in huber_loss
    math_ops.multiply(delta, linear))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 326, in multiply
    return gen_math_ops.mul(x, y, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 4689, in mul
    "Mul", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 546, in _apply_op_helper
    inferred_from[input_arg.type_attr]))
TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type int32 of argument 'x'.
```

NOTE:
Used precompiled wheels to install tensorflow
There was an error with protobuf compiler that has been solved by 
removing this line
reserved 6; (line number 104)
in ssd.proto on object_detection/protos folder
I found this solution here but i couldnt find the link

Here is the script to start training

```
PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH=/home/nvidia/testtraining/models/model/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
MODEL_DIR=/home/nvidia/testtraining/models/model/
NUM_TRAIN_STEPS=50000
NUM_EVAL_STEPS=2000
python3 object_detection/model_main.py \
    --pipeline_config_path=${PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH} \
    --model_dir=${MODEL_DIR} \
    --num_train_steps=${NUM_TRAIN_STEPS} \
    --num_eval_steps=${NUM_EVAL_STEPS} \
    --alsologtostderr
```

Laptop TF version 1.10.0

Jetson TX2 tf version 1.6.0-rc1

I m new to Ubuntu and Tensorflow so go easy on me :)

Thanks

EDIT:
It seems like line 546, in _apply_op_helper is some sort of error handling line.
I tried to fix this error with following edit. Added these. In /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py Added these to line 236 just after define statement

```
import tensorflow as tf
y = tf.cast(y, x.dtype)
```

This created some other error message which is solved by editing /home/nvidia/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/matchers/argmax_matcher.py line 203-204 to these

```
indicator = tf.cast(1-indicator, x.dtype)
return tf.add(tf.multiply(x, indicator), val * indicator)
```

But i m still getting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/model_main.py", line 101, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "object_detection/model_main.py", line 97, in main
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 425, in train_and_evaluate
    executor.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 504, in run
    self.run_local()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 636, in run_local
    hooks=train_hooks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 355, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 824, in _train_model
    features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 805, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nvidia/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_lib.py", line 287, in model_fn
    prediction_dict, features[fields.InputDataFields.true_image_shape])
  File "/home/nvidia/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py", line 686, in loss
    keypoints, weights)
  File "/home/nvidia/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py", line 859, in _assign_targets
    groundtruth_weights_list)
  File "/home/nvidia/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/core/target_assigner.py", line 481, in batch_assign_targets
    anchors, gt_boxes, gt_class_targets, unmatched_class_label, gt_weights)
  File "/home/nvidia/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/core/target_assigner.py", line 180, in assign
    match = self._matcher.match(match_quality_matrix, **params)
  File "/home/nvidia/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/core/matcher.py", line 239, in match
    return Match(self._match(similarity_matrix, **params),
  File "/home/nvidia/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/matchers/argmax_matcher.py", line 190, in _match
    _match_when_rows_are_non_empty, _match_when_rows_are_empty)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 432, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2047, in cond
    orig_res_t, res_t = context_t.BuildCondBranch(true_fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 1897, in BuildCondBranch
    original_result = fn()
  File "/home/nvidia/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/matchers/argmax_matcher.py", line 153, in _match_when_rows_are_non_empty
    -1)
  File "/home/nvidia/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/matchers/argmax_matcher.py", line 203, in _set_values_using_indicator
    indicator = tf.cast(1-indicator, x.dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 983, in r_binary_op_wrapper
    x = ops.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=y.dtype.base_dtype, name="x")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 950, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1040, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 235, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 214, in constant
    value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 433, in make_tensor_proto
    _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 344, in _AssertCompatible
    (dtype.name, repr(mismatch), type(mismatch).__name__))
TypeError: Expected bool, got 1 of type 'int' instead.
```

And this one is out of my leage

I think there is a huge compatability issues and i will just install tf 1.1 instead
I m open to new ideas though

Answer (score 0):

The key to your problem is here(bottom of traceback):

```
   TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type int32 of argument 'x'.
```

your y has type float32, but argument - x(place where you pass this y to), needs to be int32.

Try using tf.cast(y, tf.int32) or something like that.

Sometimes there are some changes in tf/you use some older model versions. So this may happen from time to time.

So just open
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py"

find line 546, and do that cast. (using sudo vim, i guess)